# How to show that $\{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2n^2x}\}$ from an orthonormal basis in $L^2(0,\frac{2}{\pi})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

So here is my problem,

I would like to prove that $\{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2 n^2x}:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ form an orthonormal basis for  $L^2([0,\frac{2}{\pi}])$ functions with respect to,

$$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_{[0,\frac{2}{\pi}]}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$$
An easy computations shows that,

$\langle \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2n^2x},\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2m^2x}\rangle=\delta_{n,m}$
hence $\{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2n^2x}:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is an orthormal system of vectors. So it is left to show that $\{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2n^2x}:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is indeed maximal i.e a basis.

For that I wanted to show that if for $f\in L^2[(0,\frac{2}{\pi})]$, we have,

$$\langle f,\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi^2n^2x}\rangle=0\;\forall n\in \mathbb Z$$
then it follows $f\equiv0$ and hence the system is maximal. But I am failing to show that...

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, how did you show that it is a basis?

Comment: What do you get if you take the inner product of your elements with $e^{i\pi^2 3x}$?